# do I have to remove the self signed SSL certificate before creating the CSR request?

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a self signed ssl certificate on my server at the moment and I've bought a CA signed one. I'm about to generate the CSR Request, will my previously installed self signed one conflict with my attempts at making a new one? Do I have to remove all traces of my self signed one first? I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A self signed cert and a CA certificate are basically the same thing. They all need the a CSR and a private key in order for them to function.

Replacing the cert on Apache is very simple. Just go to your httpd config file and point to the new Private key, Domain Cert, and Intermediate Cert. Restart the service and finish!

Comment: You should explain a little more. You cant just throw a surface answer.

Answer (score 0):

No. When you import the signed certificate it will overwrite the self-signed one. Make sure you use the same alias.